AppInsights and Sitecore logs logged simultaneously
Is there a possibility to log Sitecore logs simultaneously to log files and AppInsights?
Original patch config looks like does not support this by default as you can either turn it on or off in web.config for AppInsights by setting useApplicationInsights to true or false:

AppInsights patch config for Sitecore:


did you try to add both appender to the root ? 





Issue is that original appender uses useApplicationInsights setting in web.config to determine whether to log to AppInsights or to log4net.
There are two solutions:

rewrite original config file
write custom appender.

First option is not good for upgrade purposes (which we are planning to overcome soon) therefore I have chosen to go with second option.
Therefore, I have created another Log4Net appender and patch it inside of log4net configuration node.
<log4net>
    <appender name="Log4NetLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.SitecoreLogFileAppender, Sitecore.Logging">
        <file value="$(dataFolder)/logs/log.{date}.{time}.txt"/>
        <appendToFile value="true"/>
        <rollingStyle value="Size"/>
        <maxSizeRollBackups value="-1"/>
        <maximumFileSize value="10MB"/>
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%4t %d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p %m%n"/>
        </layout>
        <encoding value="utf-8"/>
        <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter" patch:source="Sitecore.log4net.config">
            <param name="LevelMin" value="INFO"/>
            <param name="LevelMax" value="ERROR"/>
        </filter>           
    </appender>

    <root>
        <appender-ref ref="Log4NetLogFileAppender" />
    </root>
</log4net>

The root will be responsible to add it to AppInsights appender so both will be logged
